# nginx configuration reference filename

Tags: nginx

I'm setting up nginx + uwsgi.  I plan to have multiple apps with different settings running on separate subdomains (e.g. sub1.example.com, sub2.example.com).

One of the nice things about uwsgi, is configuration rewriting. For example, I can create a skeleton for all uwsgi apps and use %n to represent the current filename (without extension).

```
$ cat > uwsgi.skel
[uwsgi]
...
socket = /var/run/uwsgi/%n.sock
...
```

Now I can just create new uwsgi instances using ln -s.

```
$ ln -s /etc/uwsgi/conf/sub1.example.com.ini /etc/uwsgi/conf/uwsgi.skel
$ ln -s /etc/uwsgi/conf/sub2.example.com.ini /etc/uwsgi/conf/uwsgi.skel
```

The nginx configuration for the servers will be exactly the same *EXCEPT* for the domain name. I'd like to do something like this:

```
cat > /etc/nginx/sites-available/app.skel
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name $file_name;
    location / { try_files $uri @app }
    location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix://var/run/uwsgi/$file_name.sock 
    }
}
$ ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sub1.example.com /etc/nginx/sites-available/app.skel
$ ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sub2.example.com /etc/nginx/sites-available/app.skel
```

Is there any way to do replacement in nginx similar to what is available with uwsgi?  What is the best way to achieve configuration sharing between nginx applications?

Comment: This answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794549/how-to-use-the-conf-files-filename-from-within-an-nginx-conf-file Use `${host}`. Done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out this is not possible with nginx.